# What to do if /usr/lib/python*/site-packages is accidentally deleted?

Tags: python, rpm, centos7

I have accidentally deleted my `site-packages` folder for python2.7.5 under `/usr/lib/` .

I have seen that if this problem happens i need to install python again.

So, i took an rpm and tried `rpm -i python*`

But, it says i have already installed python2.7.5 in my centOS 7.

I kind of got stuck, how to resolve this?

N.B. I have no Internet connection on that centOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell `rpm` to overwrite the packages. So your command should be:

```
rpm -i --replacepkgs python*
```

This of course needs the `.rpm`-packages for Python in the current directory.